# Debugging crashes due to base class size change

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

Recently I've been facing few crashes due to class size changes in base class and derived class not being compiled. Let me give you a simple example., I have a base class, 'BaseClass' present in Base.dll and I have inherited that class and created DerivedClass which is present in Derived.dll. Whenever BaseClass size changes Derived.dll should be recompiled. But it might not always be possible to find all dependent binaries and sometimes people miss a few dependent binaries. In those cases we get mysterious crashes that are very hard to debug. Is there any way to narrow down on such problems? In other words, what clues would let you think in this direction?

EDIT 1: More details. Please assume that there is more than one base class say base1, base2, base3 etc., each derived in separate dlls. derived1.dll, derived2.dll and derived3.dll. It is unnecessary to compile all other projects for  a size change in one base class. Also, making dependencies is not an option, which is why we run into this issue often.

Comment: Changes to the definition of `BaseClass` should trigger a recompile of `DerivedClass` and its dependents. Why isn't this happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fool proof option other than recompiling. If finding which classes are derived from your `class BaseClass` is an issue, then that can be solved in following way.

```
class FinalLock {
  FinalLock () {}
  friend class BaseClass;
};
```

Whenever you change the `BaseClass` size, do following:

```
class BaseClass : virtual FinalLock {
  ...
};
```

And recompile the whole project. Whichever classes derive from `BaseClass` will cause a compiler error (actually, instantiation of the classes will cause the error).

This tells you which classes are dependent on `BaseClass`. This exercise is needed only once. You can then mark all the dependent code.

Remove this extra code once you are done. With C++11, the above technique can be made still easier:

```
final class BaseClass {
^^^^^
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Method one would be to fix the dependencies so that all dependent modules are properly recompiled.  That can be a hassle across shared libraries, but see if it can't be fixed directly.

Method two would be to always "rebuild all".  Or always delete everything in the obj directory and build.

Method three would be add some debug mode code which checks the size(s) of objects and compares them with new calls across the API boundary which returns the size(s) of the objects there.